# iOS: How can I figure out the size of the view in the super view's layout?

Tags: ios, view, interface-builder, frame, bounds

[image: views screenshot]

When I use self.view.frame.size.height, it gets the height of the child nib, rather than the height of how the view is going to fit into the overall layout. I get the same value using self.view.bounds.size.height and super.view.bounds.size.height.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask at the right time. Not until the view is ready to appear has iOS figured out what size it will actually be. Move your code that depends upon the view being the right size to `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` or an `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4 you would select your view controller that contains the UIScrollView and set the 'Simulated Metrics' in the IB Attributes Inspector as follows:

[image: Attributes Inspector]

This ensures that your UIScrollView will be set to the correct size to fill the available space at design time. It looks like you are using an older version of Xcode/IB and I can't remember exactly where these settings used to be but they're in there somewhere.

With the layout designed to accommodate the space taken up by the tab bar you should be able to query the size of the UIScrollView at any time and get the correct values.

Comment: Is it possible to set this "Inferred" status programmatically?

Comment: These metrics are just used by IB while you are laying out your UI and don't make any sense at runtime. The nib file that is created specifies view coordinates and size in actual point values i.e. your UIScrollView will have width=320 and height=411 (for iPhone). Without the simulated bottom tab bar your UIScrollView will have size (320x460) in the nib.